# Easiest way of showing load progress of file uploading with html input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to upload a file from an jsp page, I know the basics.

```
    <form name="someForm" id="someFormId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="somename" size="chars"> 
    <input id="anyid" name="anyName" type="submit" value="UploadFile" class="button" />
```

I want to make a progress bar of some kind but I don't know if its possible, I read that you can do it using flash, but it would be a mess using flash on the project just for that thing.
Is there any way of capturing the progress of the load?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Not like this. Basically JavaScript has to be in control of sending the file for it to be able to report a progress. If you just do a post request your only progress indicators are 'loading' and 'done'.

Using the `FileReader` object and `FormData` object you can have JavaScript send a file and get progress results. It doesn't work in older browsers though so be cautious.

Google for more info, there are some standard solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if the browser supports one of several methods.  Either FileReader/FormData (as Frits mentioned), or via Flash or another browser plugin.  You also need to do the post handling server-side.

I'm using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) at work in a number of areas where this type of functionality was needed.  I'm using a slightly modified version of the jQueryUI script/css.  It works very well, and the plugin/script author has already handled the heavy lifting for the client-side work.

NOTE: for straight html+javascript posts without flash, or limiting supported browsers, the best you can do is display an animated flash (animated gifs stop animating in the browser) as part of the "onsubmit" action for the form.